# After reordering legend in ggplot2 I cannot prevent a second legend coming up

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am trying to get a well ordered legend (Fz, Cz and Pz) of my distribution, which is empirical and thus my use of `geom_density_line`.

In case this helps, this is how my data looks.

```
> head(dframe1)
         x            y Electrode
1 1.571296 0.0001474116        Fz
2 1.576496 0.0001487649        Fz
3 1.581697 0.0001497564        Fz
4 1.586897 0.0001504074        Fz
5 1.592098 0.0001507446        Fz
6 1.597298 0.0001507776        Fz
```

I am using for this purpose `scale_fill_discrete` with the reordered breaks. Problem is, it redraws me a new legend and I cannot prevent this doing it. I believe the problem is with the `aes` introduced in `geom_density_line` but even with the use of `show.legend = FALSE` which simply prevents redrawing any legend, i cannot get rid of the one that is nor properly ordered.

```
p1 <- ggplot(data = dframe1, mapping = aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_density_line(stat = "identity", size=.5, alpha=0.3, aes(color=Electrode, fill=Electrode)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(breaks=c("Fz","Cz","Pz")) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0) +
  xlab("values") +
  xlim(-2, 10) +
  ylab("density") +
  ylim(0, .7) +
  labs(title="Interval")
```

[This is the result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ccm88.png)

What I am trying to achieve is simply having the reordered legend, the one on top.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding

```
+ guides(colour = FALSE)
```

to your ggplot call.

Comment: Sure, I was just waiting for the 10min wait, you've been way too fast :)) Thanks again pal!